# How to minimise sum of 4 different people's scores, each in distinct disciplines

Tags: algorithm

In a swimming contest, there are 4 types of different strokes. Each contestant participates in all of them and their completion times are recorded. From all the contestants, four have to be chosen such that their combined time is minimum(one contestant can be chosen for only one stroke). More than one such team may be possible and all of such teams must be printed in output.

For example, say there are four contestants A, B, C and D. Their completion times are

```
A    50.5   52.9   51.8   52.7
B    50.7   52.7   51.4   52.7
C    50.7   52.7   51.4   52.8
D    50.8   52.9   51.6   52.6
```

Here, the minimum time would be (A - 50.5, C - 52.7, B - 51.4, D - 52.6) and (A - 50.5, B - 52.7, C - 51.4, D - 52.6).

I don't have any test cases for this. I can do it using brute force but that would take O(n^4). What would be a better approach?

Comment: "The following" is really a bad choice for a title.

Comment: If I understand the problem correctly, transform your data from rows to columns, and then choose minimums across columns. This will take O(n log n)

Comment: sounds like a homework question....what have you tried or do you have a couple of different ideas that you've tried?

Comment: @AndyG thought about that but there might be more than one combination. How to tackle that?

Comment: @random brute force works but it's O(n^4) , other than that I thought about sorting each column but than more than one person might have the lowest time in two or more categories and there might be at most n! possible answers.

Comment: @trincot sorry but I couldn't think of anything else. Would be happy to change if you suggest anything else.

Comment: @trincot what if all the timings are same for all the swimmers? Won't there be n! possible combinations?

Comment: Yes, in that case it amounts to all (4 out of n) combinations, which is *O(n^4)*. And since that is the number of items in the desired output, there is no way to produce that in lesser order of time complexity. But swimming times are in practice hardly ever exactly the same (note  that they are measured in [hundreds of a second](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_record_progression_50_metres_freestyle))

Comment: @trincot true but it was just an online interview contest and I actually wasted an hour trying to get the time complexity down. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

There's no point in taking the fifth or worse best time in a stroke: one of the top four is available regardless of how we want to assign the other three strokes. Take the top four candidates in each stroke and then filter the `4*4*4*4 = 256` possibilities to make sure that the assignments are unique.

**O(n)** (assuming that the number of races is constant).

Since you need all of the solutions, there's no way to get an O(n)-time solutions, since there may be exponentially many of them. You can enumerate them efficiently using the algorithm above, however. In your brute-force algorithm, insert a test that uses the above logic to determine whether the partial assignment being considered can be extended to an optimal solution. The running time is **O(n + s)**, where s is the number of optimal solutions.

Comment: what if n candidates all have the same timings for all the races, won't there be n! teams? how to calculate that in O(n) or O(nlogn)?

Comment: @d1729 Then you use the logic above to prune brute force.